# hadoop installation

Tags: java, hadoop

After I tried to format the nameNode (for the first time). I received this message 3 times:
"localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set". I checked my hadoop-env.sh twice to make sure I have set up JAVA HOME correctly, which indeed I did. "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun" was there.

Why do I receive that message?

BTW, I am using hadoop-0.20.203.0.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your .bash_profile and add the Java path

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

- Save the .bash_profile file and type the following command

> $> source ~/.bash_profile

(This will set up your environment variables)

- Now check the status

Comment: $> source ~/.bash_profile results in bash: source: Permission denied. with source .bash_profile i got the same result.

Comment: Type $> chattr -i .bash_profile....this unsets the file as immutable. 
And then execute $> source ~/.bash_profile . Kindly check this site : http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24293&page=1

Comment: Otherwise, type this $> su <username> enter and then enter the password. Afterwards , try $> source ~/.bash_profile (Hadoop must be  installed on that username ). Jst comment if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Do you have separate user for hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your system setup there is something you could check.

If using a package manager, often times Hadoop is installed with a separate user. Is it possible that you ran hadoop as a for instance "hadoop" user which has not enough rights to access JRE?

Answer (score 0):

I had read you problems and comments.As you configured your hadoop under hduser, you need to edit $HOME/.bashrc and set the java home path like I did in my PC:

`# Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

And if you get any permission problem then I'll suggest you to follow proper steps to gain permission for hduser like ssh-keygen. For now I'll recommend you to simply shift to root and then edit the file with specifying hduser path.

You can also refer to this blog for proper installation steps:
http://data-flair.training/blogs/setup-hadoop-2-yarn-psedo-distributed-mode/

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to know the right path of java:

```
update-alternatives --config  java
```

Copy the whole path before `/jre`:

```
edit .bashrc file by using this command $ nano -/.bashrc
```

Copy the path in this file like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting Variable won't help, because hadoop fetch JAVA_HOME variable value only from **hadoop-env.sh**.

I followed this steps to resolve my issue:

**Step-1:** *Use the following command to confirm the JAVA_HOME value:*

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/
```

You can see the JAVA folders...

**Step-2:** *Open the $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh. Command:*

```
sudo nano $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

**Step-3:** *Uncommnent the JAVA_HOME and Enter the value from Step-1.*

Now try your command again, this time it would work.